# Difference between Apache HTTP Client and Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I'm making a call to the Google Translate API, one via Apache HTTP Client and one via Spring's RestTemplate, and getting different results back. Both are GETing exactly the same URL:

I want to translate "Professeur des écoles" from French to English.

The URL used is (split onto two lines for sake of readability):

```
private static String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?
key=AIzaSyBNv1lOS...&source=fr&target=en&q=Professeur+des+%C3%A9coles";
```

Apache:

```
@Test
public void apache() throws IOException {
    String response = Request.Get(URL).execute().returnContent().asString();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Returns (correctely):

{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": **"School teacher"**
   }
  ]
 }
}

```
@Test
public void spring() {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    String response = template.getForObject(URL, String.class);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Returns (incorrectely):

{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": **"Professor + of +% C3% A9coles"**
   }
  ]
 }
}

Am I missing something in RestTemplate HTTP header configuration?

Comment: First thing to do is figure out what exactly each client is sending in the request. There are different ways to do that - what I would do is use netcat to open a listening socket on your machine, then change to URL so it points to localhost - netcat then will print out the HTTP request verbatim.

Comment: My guess is that the Spring client is doing something funky to the encoded 'é' character. Does it work correctly when the phrase has only ASCII characters?

Comment: Yep - simple ASCII works perfectly for both - it's something to do with the encoding.

Comment: Check the http headers of both, either by using wireshark or membrane monitor proxy or alike

Comment: Post exactly the URL used for each. I suspect that RestTemplate is simply URL encoding the string you already encoded and that you should pass it an unencoded parameter.

Comment: The URL is defined statically at the top of my test - just made that more obvious by adding the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) methods that accept a `String` URL perform URL encoding.

> For each HTTP method there are three variants: two accept a URI
>   template string and URI variables (array or map) while a third accepts
>   a URI. Note that for URI templates it is assumed encoding is
>   necessary, e.g. `restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotel
>   list")` becomes `"http://example.com/hotel%20list"`. **This also means if
>   the URI template or URI variables are already encoded, double encoding
>   will occur**, e.g. `http://example.com/hotel%20list` becomes
>   `http://example.com/hotel%2520list`).

Presumably you've provided the following `String` as the first argument

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_KEY&source=fr&target=en&q=Professeur+des+%C3%A9coles
```

The character `%` must be encoded. Your `q` parameter's value therefore becomes

```
Professeur%2Bdes%2B%25C3%25A9coles
```

which, if you [decode](http://urldecode.org/?text=Professeur%252Bdes%252B%2525C3%2525A9coles&mode=decode), is equivalent to

```
Professeur+des+%C3%A9coles
```

Google's translation services doesn't know what to do with `%C3%A9coles`.

As the documentation suggests

> To avoid that use a URI method variant to provide (or re-use) a
>   previously encoded URI. To prepare such an URI with full control over
>   encoding, consider using [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html).

instead of using overloads that accept a `String` URL, construct a URI yourself and use that.

---

Apache's [HttpComponents Fluent API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html#Get%28java.lang.String%29) does not specify the behavior but it seems the String value is taken as is.

Comment: Ohh - I explicitly encoded the query params myself while building the URL. So I'm getting double encoded?

Comment: @Kong Basically. `RestTemplate` encodes any string URL given to it. Apache's fluent API doesn't. It takes the String raw and assumes you did it yourself.

Comment: And thanks for the answer to the Jackson question the other day - DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS worked like a charm!

Comment: You ever want to quit the Valley and move back to Europe - please ping me - we could make you a very attractive offer (I'm CTO and we're well funded). And I spend 50% of my day coding - clearly badly!

Comment: @kong That's very generous of you. Connect with me on LinkedIn if you'd like. (I'm originally from Montreal :p)