# calling request trigger url of azure logic app from RestTemplate java

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, resttemplate, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure logic app with request trigger. I want to trigger this logic app from my java application. So, I am trying to call the request trigger url from my java API.

It is working fine if i am using DefaultHttpClient but getting 401 on calling it using RestTemplate in java.

DefaultHttpClient code:

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
        "{url of azure logic app trigger}");

    //StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}");
    //input.setContentType("application/json");
    //postRequest.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }


    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return("Success");
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return("Error");
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return("Error");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return("Error");
}
```

RestTemplate Code

```
@Service
public class SampleService {
@Autowired HttpClientService<String, String> httpClientService;
public String callURL() {
ResponseErrorHandler responseErrorHandler = new ResponseErrorHandler() {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.print(response.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString("{logic app url}")
        // Add query parameter
        .queryParam("api-version", {api-version})
        .queryParam("sp", {sp})
        .queryParam("sv", {sv})
        .queryParam("sig",{sig});

RequestDetailsDAO requestDetails = new RequestDetailsDAO(builder.build().toUri().toString(), HttpMethod.GET);
String response = httpClientService.execute(requestDetails, null, responseErrorHandler, String.class);
return response.toString();
```

HttpClientService.java

```
@Service
public class HttpClientService<T, V>  {
public RestTemplate restTemplate;

public HttpClientService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).build();
}

public V execute(RequestDetailsDAO requestDetails, HttpEntity<T> entity, ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler,
                 Class<V> genericClass) {

    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    ResponseEntity<V> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestDetails.getUrl(), requestDetails.getRequestType(), entity, genericClass);
    return response.getBody();
}
}
```

RequestDetailsDAO.java

```
public class RequestDetailsDAO {
private String url;
private HttpMethod requestType;

public RequestDetailsDAO(String url, HttpMethod requestTyp) {
    super();
    this.url = url;
    this.requestType = requestTyp;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public HttpMethod getRequestType() {
    return requestType;
}
public void setRequestType(HttpMethod requestType) {
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RequestDetails [url=" + url + ", requestType=" + requestType + "]";
}
}
```

Comment: DefaultHTTPClient code is working. Need to do it using RestTemplate.

I am already passing all SAS params. sp, sv, api-verison and sig to authorize azure logic app.

Comment: Have the same exact issue when sending simple POST request to Azure Logic App with Rest Template. Using DefaultHTTPClient/CloseableHttpClient works fine... @Anmol Middha any solution found on this in the meantime?

Answer (score 4):

So, it seems that there's nothing special about LogicApps being called using RestTemplate.
It's just that RestTemplate by default URL encode the Uri given in parameter, and DefaultHttpClient does not - reference: [apache vs resttemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376190/difference-between-apache-http-client-and-spring-resttemplate)

In case of LogicApp URL, there is this "sp" parameter which is already URL endcoded, when you copy it from LogicApp -
"%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun", so you need to decode that and pass "/triggers/manual/run" to UriComponentsBuilder. And then it works.

My code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestDto, headers);

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString("https://prod-123901.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/<workflow_id>/triggers/manual/paths/invoke")
            .queryParam("api-version", "2016-10-01")
            .queryParam("sp", "/triggers/manual/run")
            .queryParam("sv", "1.0")
            .queryParam("sig", "<your_sig>");
    restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri().toString(), HttpMethod.POST, request, Void.class);
```

update:

requestDto here is your custom dto object that goes in HTTP Body, like for example object of class:

```
public class RequestDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is requestDto here refers?

Comment: editing the parameter "sp" by changing the "%2F" to "/" made my flow trigger (When a HTTP request is received) working again. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the simple standalone code with RestTemplate and check. I provide below small snippet.

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> response = restTemplate.exchange({uri of azure logic app trigger}, HttpMethod.GET, request, ResponseVO.class);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
    int statusCode = ex.getStatusCode().value();
    System.out.println("Status Code :"+statusCode);
    ResponseEntity<?> resEntity = ResponseEntity.status(ex.getRawStatusCode()).headers(ex.getResponseHeaders())
                .body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString())
}
```

Here `ResponseVO.class` is the Response to be mapped to an object, in this case, you can set your own class. In this catch block, you can find the exception details.

Comment: getting same error

"body": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AuthorizationFailed\",\"message\":\"You do not have permissions to perform action 'run' on scope '/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/'. Verify you are making the request with the appropriate HTTP method. See http://aka.ms/logic-trigger for details.\"}}",
    "statusCode": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "statusCodeValue": 401

Comment: Are you able to see the messages in catch block ? You are using GET method in httpClient, Besides are you able call using PostMan client, just to make sure that call is happening.

Comment: Are you using https or http in the uri ?

Comment: Yeah i can see the messages in catch block.I am able to call the logic app url through postman. Azure logic app is https. My java api is running on localhost(http).

Comment: How to call the Logicapp url GET request using restTemplate from spring boot controller class.